# Is Hibernate batching with IDENTITY generation possible?

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I just read this article which says how to do batching with hibernate but at the end it says it was done with `SEQUENCE` generation.  I am wondering if it is possible with `IDENTITY` generation though.  From reading around it sounds like `IDENTITY` generation is done at execute of `INSERT` which means that it could be too late?

ie. If I

```
mgr.persist(child)
mgr.persist(parent)
```

in a loop, BUT I want batching, the child would not have the id until `mgr.flush()` since the insert is delayed until flush time. Looking at `IDENTITY` generation:

> The only drawback is that we can’t know the newly assigned value prior to executing the INSERT statement.

So this is implying that I would have to then

```
mgr.persist(child), mgr.persist(child), mgr.persist(child)
```

then `mgr.flush()` for id population

then

```
mgr.persist(parent, mgr.persist(parent), mgr.persist(parent)
```

We are in mysql and 'could' switch so that we are in postgres which has better support for sequence generation AND pooling so it grabs 50 ids at a time.

My main question is if anyone has done batching with hibernate AND with `IDENTITY` generation along with child/parent relationships to slam data in for a batch?  And if so, what patterns work?  Does my above pattern work?  or am I wrong and I could do

```
mgr.persist(child), mgr.persit(parent), mgr.persist(child), mgr.persist(parent)
```

WHICH to be honest is simpler to keep as I can just loop over DTO's saving that data.

If I use UUID generation instead, I am assuming that would be much better with MysqL?  Then I don't have to worry about code order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-identity) says about this limitation:

> It is important to realize that using `IDENTITY` columns imposes a runtime behavior where the entity row **must** be physically inserted prior to the identifier value being known.
>
> This can mess up extended persistence contexts (long conversations). Because of the runtime imposition/inconsistency, Hibernate suggests other forms of identifier value generation be used (e.g. `SEQUENCE`).
>
> There is yet another important runtime impact of choosing `IDENTITY` generation: *Hibernate will not be able to batch `INSERT` statements for the entities using the `IDENTITY` generation.*
>
> The importance of this depends on the application-specific use cases. If the application is not usually creating many new instances of a given entity type using the `IDENTITY` generator, then this limitation will be less important since batching would not have been very helpful anyway.

Comment: good to know @StemK and what about UUID generations(I guess I wrote GUID in the post...whoops).

Comment: @DeanHiller As far as I know [UUID generation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-uuid) does not have such limitation. But I have to say what using UUID lead you to use a hibernate specific facility since JPA spec does not [support](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-simple) it.